# Finding the number of different dates in a string

Tags: regex

I am stuck in a question. A paragraph which contained some dates in format DD-MM-YYYY, find number of distinct years in the paragraph .Can this be solved using regex?

Comment: Pure regex alone can't do this, but regex could be used to isolate and extract the dates.  What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: Also, please post some sample inputs and outputs for the same.

Comment: I am using JAVA. 
Some random words with date 12-01-1990 and some more words with date 12-12-2017 and again some random words with same date 12-05-1990.
Expected Output: 3
Since it contains 3 dates

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

Regex for date `var regex = /(?:(?:[0-2][0-9]|[3][01])-(?:[0][13578]|[1][02])|(?:[0-2][0-9]|30)-(?:[0][469]|11)|(?:[0-2][0-9])-02)-[0-9]{4}/g;`.

The above regex cannot match leap years.

To find the count of dates in the pargraph in JS is

```
function dateCount(input){
    const regex = /(?:(?:[0-2][0-9]|[3][01])-(?:[0][13578]|[1][02])|(?:[0-2][0-9]|30)-(?:[0][469]|11)|(?:[0-2][0-9])-02)-[0-9]{4}/g;
    let m;
    var noDates= 0; 
    while ((match = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
        dateCounter++; 
//This is to prevent from running into infinite loop
        if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }
    }
    console.log(dateCounter);
}
```